# jquery not run parent page's script when it use $.get and append data into it

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$.get('page.php', function(data){
   $('#container').append(data);
});

$('.delete').click(function(){
 alert();
});
```

I have a page use get to fetch & append more data into the page,

in my main page, i have a button script for class delete, this works for all button in main page, but not the new data append into, is any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an [event delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1688293/3269863) issue. The click handler is only set on elements present at the time the code is executed.

Try:

```
$('body').on('click', '.delete', function(){
 alert();
});
```

`body` is here just a placeholder for any parent element of `.delete`. Try to attach the handler to a parent element with as less child elements as possible (in your example `#container` seems appropriate) to prevent performance issues.

Comment: Should really be using `$('#container').on(...);` so it's bound as close to the dynamic elements as possible.

Comment: Yeah i'm aware of that, but i wanted to briefly explain the issue + we do not know if the OP has some other elements to be added, that won't be children of `#container`. But it's a fair point as i have mentioned.